# SQL AlwaysOn Configuration

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

I have configured the following AG configuration in Azure
3 VM's (SQL 2019)

Server1 & Server2 are in the same region and is configured with Automatic failover and synchronous commit mode
Server3 is in another region and configured with Manual Failover and Asynchronous commit mode.
So, under normal operations:
AG is active on Server1
Cluster quorum is configured as Server1 & Server2 having a vote with a file share witness.

So, if I were to failover to DR (Server3), my idea is as follows:

- Change Server3 to Synchronous commit mode
- Failover AG to Server3
- Change Server1 & Server2 to Asynchronous commit mode with manual failover
- Remove cluster quorum votes from Server1 & Server2
- Assign Server3 a cluster quorum vote.

If I were to failback to Server1 my idea is as follows:

- Change Server1 & Server2 to Synchronous commit mode
- Failover AG to Server1
- Change Server3 to Asynchronous commit mode
- Remove cluster quorum votes from Server3
- Assign cluster quorum votes to Server1 & Server2

Am I on the right track here?
Is the order of my steps perhaps a problem?

Any advice would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I on the right track here?

I see, overall, what you're attempting to do and there's nothing incorrect in the big picture.

> So, if I were to failover to DR (Server3), my idea is as follows: [...]

The last two steps should be reversed, Server3 would need to have it's node weight set before removing the other two. Whether or not you want sync/async is a personal decision, though it might be based on some resource scarcity in the setup or across regions.

> If I were to failback to Server1 my idea is as follows: [...]

Same issue here, the last two steps should be reversed.

> Any advice would be appreciated

The only thing you may want to consider is breaking this up to be a distributed AG versus a regular AG, given it's across regions, you're only using async, and specifically trying to avoid one side having votes.

Comment: Great - Thanks.
My main concern was actually the node weight settings with regards to the order of things.